# Generate same random number on both client and server in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, meteor

Using Meteor, I need a method to generate the same random number on both the client and server, so I can get the benefits of the client method's latency compensation.

I noticed Meteor has a random package: http://docs.meteor.com/#random

I'm not familiar with random number generation or crytography and I don't really understand some of the Meteor documentation for the Random package, so I have some questions.

1. Can I use this package to achieve what I want?
2. If yes, how do I use it to do that? If I use a seed on the client to generate the random number and then send that seed to the server to regenerate the same number, then isn't that implicitly an insecure way to do it... because the client can't be trusted?
3. If no, is there another way to achieve this?

My problem definition in steps...

1. CLIENT: Generate seed
2. CLIENT: Generate random number from seed
3. CLIENT: Send seed to server
4. SERVER: Generate random number from seed
5. Fail... client generated seed can be peeked at and is open to manipulation

The alternative:

1. CLIENT: Ask server for random number
2. SERVER: Generate random number
3. SERVER: Send random number to client
4. Fail... round trip means that you can't take advantage of Meteor's latency compensation

My app needs to repeatedly generate a lot of random numbers, so I'm trying to avoid all these round trips.

Comment: "I need a method to generate the same random number on both the client and server" - the fact you need to do that suggests you may be solving the problem incorrectly....

Comment: @MitchWheat How would you suggest I solve the problem? Just generate it on the server and send the result to the client (i.e. authoritative)? I'm trying to avoid the round trip... not sure if it's possible though.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the problem is, but I suspect the answer is "Use a GUID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of thing you want to achieve, if we take the example of a slot machine in a MMO, what is done step by step is this:

1. User clicks on the "Insert Coin" button
2. Server receives a notification the user paid for one play, the result from the play is sent to client
3. The client waits for the user to spin the machine and starts rolling
4. The client shows the result it had received while waiting for user action + animation.

This has one side effect: the result can be known by the user before he even starts spinning the wheel, but after he paid for it.

The problem is that if the user has different options to choose AFTER the random number is picked, he could choose the option with the lowest cost if he finds the number to be a bad one. To remedy to this, each random action needs to have their own number created.

You could see this schema detailed by a user who looked at sources of a game to find out he was "cheated" by the game: [Zoot Loot is Not Random](http://edgeworldhacks.blogspot.fr/2011/10/zoot-loot-is-not-random.html)

In a flash game called clickerheroes, there are actions producing a random result. Since the game is saved once every couple minutes, and is not backed by a server, the random numbers are generated in advance. This prevents the trick to save, try your luck, load back, retry your luck as the same random number comes back...

Although this does not answer exactly to the OP, I hope it helps in the logic of providing trustworthy randoms to your users.

Comment: In the end I went with client generated random numbers which means I can take advantage of the latency compensation. But I also asynchronously send the results to the server as well. If the server sees the user getting too many positive results then it tells the user's client to start running all of it's requests past the server first. So legitimate users aren't punished with slow roundtrips - only potentially dodgy ones. This solution won't work in an environment that can't allow ANY cheating at all, but for me it was ok that a minor amount of cheating occurred before the security kicked in.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is insecure by nature. If you want security, call the server and wait for a response. The randomiser algorithm is available and sending the seed to the client or to server defeat this silly attempt of defence.

You should never trust data that comes from clients, always validate everything in a environment when you've complete control like your server.

Comment: It's not insecure by nature. Giving the client a seed to allow it to latency compensate the server's response is safe. Latency compensation in Meteor is UI only and everything will be overwritten by the server's response anyway. The server is still authoritative, and if the client manipulates anything, all they are doing is messing with their own UI.

Comment: Wrong, this is insecure by nature. When you generate a random number you don't want the seed to be public otherwise an attacker can deduce the next generated numbers and play with your system. This a very simple scenario: Don't share server code with the client.

Comment: Trusting the client with the seed is insecure, yes. But your answer stated "you should never trust data that comes from clients" which is not how latency compensation works, the client just simulates what it thinks the server will do, I think it should rather state "you should never trust your clients with secret data"

Comment: "the client just simulates what it thinks the server will do" - Wrong, the client tries to modify the Collection and the server either approves it or not. There is no simulation at all and you should never trust data that comes from the client, you need to perform the validation server side. If you actually try to simulate, it means you have all the logic in the clients and visible to attackers.

Comment: "There is no simulation at all" https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-latency-compensation.html

Comment: You can't simulate the server actions on the client without sending sensitive code to the client. Quoting you: "But your answer stated "you should never trust data that comes from clients" which is not how latency compensation works" - Wrong, latency compensation has nothing to with it. Data validation is absolutely necessary. Unless you provide a proof I maintain my statement: "this is insecure by nature".

Answer (score 0):

You can't seed (what you really want to do!) Math.random, and I don't think the Random package has support for it neither. You could use [seedrandom.js](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom), and seed it with the same on the server and the client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I may be misunderstanding a key part of the workflow for this, but if the client is generating the seed (because the client action happens first), then that's open to manipulation. This will only work if the server generates the seed... and that's my dilemma, because I'm trying to take advantage of Meteor's client side latency compensation, which is effectively creating a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: @Harley Is it bad enough the client can peek at the next random number, or can the server generate the seed in the beginning of the session when the client logs in, and then store it during the session? And each time the client use a random number the server checks it against it's own random number.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible for client's to see the incoming seed and figure out how to generate the random numbers in advance so that they could predict whats going to happen?  A work colleague suggested an alternative... just let the client do the number generation and send results to the server at the end. If the server records 3 positive outcomes in a row, then assume the user is 'cheating' and tell the client that it needs to start checking it's outcomes with the server from then on. Obviously this will only work if you don't mind a little bit of 'cheating', but for my use case this is fine.

Comment: @Harley Yes, it would. I guess you have to let the server generate the random numbers then.